# How to convert a JSON to work as Class for creating object

Tags: javascript, json, oop

Here is my JSON

```
var nodeclienthash={
  socket:null,
  init : function() {
    // initialize socket.io
    this.socket = new io.Socket(this.config.host, {port: this.config.port, rememberTransport: false});
 }
};
```

For now i want to create only two object , how should i create that ?

Comment: This is not JSON, this is JavaScript.

Comment: @cdhowie JSON = JavaScript Object Notation, so, Rahul is right =)!

Comment: No, he is not.  The `function()` construct, the `var` keyword, the `=` token, statements... none of these are valid JSON.  Do not confuse the JavaScript object literal syntax with the JSON specification.  All valid JSON strings are valid JavaScript expressions; not all valid JavaScript expressions are valid JSON strings.

Comment: So what about JSON-callbacks? Don't you consider them valid JSONs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function NodeClientHash() {
    this.socket = null;
    this.init = function() {
        this.socket = new io.Socket(this.config.host, {port: this.congig.port, rememberTransport: false});
    }
}

var client = new NodeClientHash();
```

Comment: it means i have toconvert my hash to function

Comment: Yes! But, actually, when you use `this` in functions, combined with the `new` keyword, you could call this a class =)!